# Weights argument in lm and lme very different in R- am I using them correctly?

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, weighted-regression

So, it seems to me that the weights function in lm gives observations more weight the larger the associated observation's 'weight' value, while the lme function in lme does precisely the opposite. This can be verified with a simple simulation.

```
#make 3 vectors- c is used as an uninformative random effect for the lme model
a<-c(1:10)
b<-c(2,4,6,8,10,100,14,16,18,20)
c<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
```

If you were now to run a model where you weight the observations based on the inverse of the dependent variable in lm, you can only generate the exact same result in nlme if you weight by just the dependent variable, without taking the inverse.

```
summary(lm(b~a,weights=1/b))
summary(lme(b~a,random=~1|c,weights=~b))
```

You can flip this and see the converse is true- specifying weights=b in lm requires weights=1/b to get a matching lme result.

So, I understand this much, I just want validation on one thing and to ask a question about another.

1. If I want to weight my data based on the inverse of the dependent variable, is it fine to just code weights=~(dependent variable) within lme?
2. Why is lme written to handle weights completely differently than lm? What is the purpose of this other than to generate confusion?

Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: The answer to 2. is that they were written by very different people to do very different things. `lm()` needed to compatible with S and various books, **nlme** didn't, and it aimed to be more flexible, allowing the heterogeneity to be modelled more flexibly than `lm` allows.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### Q1

In `lme` the notation `weights = ~ b` would result in the `varFixed` variance function being used with sole argument `b`. This function would add to the model a variance function $s^2(v)$ that has the form $s^2(v) = |v|$, where $v$ takes the values of the vector argument `b`.

Hence, you should use `weights = ~ I(1/b)` in `lme()` to have the *variance* of $\varepsilon_i = 1/b_i$.

In `lm` what you pass `weights` seems is the exact opposite; `weights` is *inversely* proportional to the variance.

I'm not 100% sure what you mean by *weight my data*, but if you mean provide the heterogeneous variance of the observations, then I think you want `weights = ~ I(1/b)`.

#### Q2

My gut feeling (you'd have to ask the respective authors of the two functions) is that this is beacuse `lm()` and `lme()` were written by very different people to do very different things. `lm()` needed (was desired to be) to be compatible with S and various books, **nlme** didn't, and it aimed to be more flexible, allowing the heterogeneity to be modelled more flexibly than `lm` allows through the use of variance *functions* via the `varFunc` infrastructure.

Comment: This is clear enough. By 'weight my data' I mean I want the model fit to consider that that large residuals should be expected from large observations, and fit something akin to percentage least squares, rather than ordinary least squares. ALSO- I deleted the cross post on stack overflow, sorry!

Comment: You might want to look at other variance functions in **nlme** then. What you are doing is saying that the variances of your observations are exactly the (absolute) value of `b`. It would seem better to just say that the variance increased with `b`. `varPower()` for example would have the variance as $\hat{\sigma}^2 \times |b|^{2\delta}$ with $\delta$ estimated a model parameter. This is OK if `b` doesn't take 0 values. If it can take 0 values, then the `varExp()` function may be better, there the variance is $var(\varepsilon_i) = \hat{\sigma}^2 \times e^{2\delta \times b_i}$.

Comment: In `lm()`, note the wording that the variance is *proportional* to the inverse of `weights`. In the `lme` code we discussed, `b` **is** the variance. Following your explanation, I don't think you really want that... Also note that if the variance increases with mean response, then a GLMM may be appropriate and the **lme4** package would be suitable as it can model the mean-variance relationship directly, rather than via modification to the covariance matrix - which is what the `lme` code is doing.

Comment: Finally, sorry if I sounded grumpy on [so]. It wasn't intentional. I just forgot that you can't vote to close as OT & migrate to [stats.se]. You have to leave a comment as to why but I'd already left the first comment. Don't choose a SE site for your question based on the number of eyes that will see it. Choose the most appropriate venue. There is nothing wrong with promoting your question on [stats.se] to get more eyes, you could even post the link to it in the R public Chat Room on [so]. Crossposting or posting OT questions dilutes the resource if we have too many, hence close votes etc.